I should jolly well hope so

I should jolly well hope so.

What's the meaning of this sentence? (in what tone, for example, angry or happy)

We can't tell the tone, because we can't hear the person, or see their attitude, or know the context.  It's casual, and rather stereotypically British.  If you used this kind of language around me, I'd think you were "taking the piss" and making fun of my Britishness (unless I knew you rather better)

It could be said angrily, but only by someone who is not accustomed to swearing or is being careful to avoid it. A really angry person would say "I should *damn well hope so" *or any expletive of your choice.

It often expresses a kind of minimal approval e.g. My wife: The man next door has apologised for insulting your mother. Me: I should jolly well hope so!

Note that well here is an intensifier (compare I like my steak well done). And jolly here is also an intensifier (compare For he's a jolly good fellow). But as implied by @JamesK's comment, such use of jolly is almost exclusively informal British (and becoming somewhat dated), so we wouldn't normally expect to hear it in a foreign accent, except facetiously. And hope here is typical British understatement for expect (in the sense of demand, require), so I shoud jolly well hope so means emphatic I expect nothing less!

@FumbleFingers - I have a Dutch friend who says things like 'This is jolly good fun!' and I find her very charming.

@MichaelHarvey: She may have picked that one up over 50 years ago! Does she have any grandchildren, and would you expect to hear the same from them? :)

@FumbleFingers - she was 60 this year; has been living in the UK for 30 years. I say 'jolly' quite a lot. Are under-30s the arbiters of language now? I'm quite a hep cat, daddy-o!

"Jolly well" is a typically British adverbial phrase that means "extremely" or "very". It's informal in the sense that it is used conversationally and colloquially; however, it is strongly associated with 'posher' regional dialects and is quite old-fashioned; as such it can sound a little stuffy even though not formal.
As an intensifier, it's used to emphasize an opinion or the truth of what's being said. It can be used in all kinds of contexts, so really it is impossible to tell the "tone" of it from your quoted text. You'd have to hear the spoken tone to be sure. That said, because it is somewhat old-fashioned and associated with 'educated' accents, in modern use it is often said to sound deliberately contrived, for a different kind of emphasis.
